# Is there a way to show the list of tags passed to the kernel from the bootloader (ARM)?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, bootloader

I would like to see the list of tags (specifically ATAG_MEM) passed to the kernel from the bootloader. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The initial entry code, [`head-common.S`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/head-common.S) will put the physical address as passed by the bootloader into the `__atags_pointer` kernel variable just after starting the MMU. That's where the later steps, `setup_arch()` calling `setup_machine_*()` (in [`arch/arm/kernel/atags_parse.c`](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/atags_parse.c)) then retrieve it from. See there for how to access physically-mapped mem.

"Seeing" them at this stage requires some early-boot-`printk` support, a JTAG debugger or some other mechanism to extract tracing / diagnostic from the device before the driver stack is fully initialized. If that (the ability to extract diagnostics early in boot of your device) is your problem, please clarify the question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I noticed that there's a kernel configuration switch CONFIG_ATAGS_PROC which allows viewing the tags from /proc/atags.

Comment: I thought you were looking to get your hands on them e.g. from kernel driver code or early init code or some such.  
Agreed, from a fully-up-and-running system it's much easier ;-) You could've extracted them directly from `/dev/mem` if you can retrieve `__atags_pointer` (`/dev/kmem` would do that job but isn't always there). The procfs interface is much more convenient though.